# Getting Exception With DB2 Auto Increment

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, netbeans, db2

I have created the following table:

```
"CREATE TABLE ParsonCollection "
                + "(id integer not null GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),"
                + "name varchar(20),"
                + "eye varchar(20),"
                + "hair varchar(20),"
                + "height varchar(20),"
                + "weight varchar(20),"
                + "PRIMARY KEY (id))";
```

I am then trying to insert into the table and this is where I am running into issues. When I try to alter the "id" column, I get an error saying "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Attempt to modify an identity column 'ID'. " Here is what the insert statement looks like:

```
"insert into ParsonCollection values(" + q_surround(Name) + ","
            + q_surround(Eye) + "," + q_surround(Hair) + "," + q_surround(Height) + "," + q_surround(Weight) + ",1" + ")";
```

However, when I take away the field that is inserting into "id", I get the following error: "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: The number of values assigned is not the same as the number of specified or implied columns." Here is what this insert statement looks like:

```
"insert into ParsonCollection values(" + q_surround(Name) + ","
            + q_surround(Eye) + "," + q_surround(Hair) + "," + q_surround(Height) + "," + q_surround(Weight) + ")";
```

How do I get past this? It seems that when I solve one exception, the other one pops up and vice versa. Thanks.

Comment: .... please be aware that the string concatenation you're doing is vulnerable to SQL Injection.  Although it won't solve your current problem, you should be using a Prepared Statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign to an identity column. Since you cannot pass all values for insert, you need to enumerate the columns (omitting the identity column):

```
"insert into ParsonCollection (
    name,
    eye,
    hair,
    height
    weight
) values(" 
    + q_surround(Name) 
    + "," + q_surround(Eye) 
    + "," + q_surround(Hair) 
    + "," + q_surround(Height)
    + "," + q_surround(Weight)
+ ")";
```

Side note: your code is opened to SQL injection. You should seriously consider using prepared statements and bind parameters instead of concatenating the query string.

Comment: what, no comment on the SQL Injection flaw?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: you are sure right. Warning added to my answer.

Comment: Thank You, this worked. The reason I'm not using prepared statements btw is because my professor doesn't allow us to and he hasn't taught them.

Answer (score 1):

Out of interest, another solution would be to make the identity column `IMPLICITLY HIDDEN`